# React: Can't access property>object stored in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get my `JSON` data like so:

```
const channel = pusher.subscribe("channel");
channel.bind("event", data => {
  this.setState({ data }); //this data is an object
 //the above code is in a componentDidMount or componentWillMount method.
```

This is what I'd like to do.

```
render() {
  return <Text> {this.state.data.high} </Text>
}
```

**OR**

```
render() {
  return <Text> {this.state.data["high"]} </Text>
}
```

However nothing's displayed.

This works:

```
render() {
  return <Text> {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)} </Text>
}
```

*And this is my initial state*

```
state = {
  data: []
};
```

Edit: The data exists and it is successfully received as well as added to state. I just can't seem to access it.

Edit 2: I can access the data (*can be logged in console*) . However it can't be displayed by the `<Text />` component.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Where are you setting initial state?

Comment: initially data is an `array`, if it is an `object` then initialise it with `data: {}`, and check where key `high` exist in that `object` or not.

Comment: @CD-jS no errors. And I'm using ES7 property initalizers to initialize state like I've written above.

Comment: @Mayank Shukla I've tried setting it to `{}` , `[{ }]` and even `Object` and `Array` . None work.

Comment: And yes the properties I try to access in the object exist.

Comment: Would you mind to add the `JSON` returned in `data`?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca `{"currencyPair":"BTC_BELA","last":"0.00008318"
,"lowestAsk":"0.00008318","highestBid":"0.00008295","percentChange":"-0.00168026","baseVolume":"67.955816
95","quoteVolume":"817938.49592671","isFrozen":0,"high":"0.00008408","low":"0.00008170"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Turns out my `Text` component wasn't styled properly that's why it wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this to show json data have a look

```
constructor(props) {
  super();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
      ''
    ]),
  }
}
```

... request

```
.then((responseData) => {
  var arrayOutput=[];
  for (var k in responseData)
   arrayOutput.push(responseData[k]);

  this.setState({
     dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(arrayOutput)
  });
})
```

and then just I use ListView to show the data

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}                            
   renderRow={(rowData) =>
   <Text>{rowData.id}</Text>                         
   <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>                         
}/>
```

Comment: That isn't going to work, `this.state.data.something` will always be undefined.

Comment: whats's the difference between your answer and this: `this.setState({data: data})`, whats the benefit of iterating the array and creating of copy of that then setting into state variable ?

Comment: @MayankShukla The difference is that @Brunaine has changed the value type in state(`data` was an object, but would now be an `array`). Which means that neither the code in the original question will work, nor the code in the example they have provided.

Comment: I always do it like this and then use the ListView and it works maybe i miss understood sorry

Comment: @CD-jS iterating for that is not required, you can directly write it like this: `this.setState({data: Object.values(data)})`

Comment: I updated the answer, I usually do it like that to show data from a request Json, take a look it may help

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments mentions, your state should be initialised with an empty `object`, rather than an `array`.

Ensure the event bound to your subscription is being called by placing a breakpoint or console.log inside your callback here:

```
channel.bind('event', data => {
    this.setState({ data });
});
```

Things to try -

- Is that callback for the data definitely being fired?
- Is the data returned to the callback definitely an object and does not require JSON.parse?
- Does it work if you set the initial state to be `{data: { high: 'SOME TEXT' } }`
- Take `<Text>` out of the mix, and try just with `<div>`, is there any special logic inside the `<Text>` component that might cause it not to update when its props change?

**Edit: Removed example component due to extra information provided**

Comment: It's ES7 property initalizers.

Comment: Unfortunately answered before that bit of information, will edit accordingly.

Comment: I will try all your suggestions shortly . And the Text component is a React Native component . This is for React Native.